# Running into errors while implementing model in keras

Tags: keras, tf.keras

I am not able to create the model in Keras as I am running into some errors. Please help

[Error while implementing model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r7zaw.png)

Comment: Please never include text as images, your error should be put as text.

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow 2.0 does not have 'get_default graph'. So, remove it from the function 'create model'. It should work then.